# AngularJS directive - template from $scope with other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

A bit confused with binding...

How to properly bind values from input fields to textarea?

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!'
  //this template comes from json
  $scope.fromjson = "{{hello}} {{world}} and have a good time";
  //this template comes from json
});
```

And a simple body:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="hello">
  <input ng-model="world">
  <helloworld></helloworld>
  </body>
```

A have to edit my miserable example because your 
kindly answers didn't solve my problem.

I had plenty of unique texts - letter templates in which some fields should be filled by user. There are ten fields occuring conditionally depending of text selected.

```
text1: "Blah, blah {{field.first}}.blah {{filed.second}}" 
text2: "{{field.third}} blah, blah {{field.first}}"
text3: "Blah, blah {{field.fourth}}"
and so on...
```

Texts are stored in database and obtained through JSON

```
 function(textid) {
    $http.get('json/json.php',
    {    params: { id: textid } }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.SelectedText = data;
    })
    };
```

I organized it in  one form with all ten input fields, visible depending of
selected text.
Completed/filled template should be visible in textarea at the bottom of form to be copied to another place.

- Should I change the way I store the templates?
- or back to question is there any other way the fields could be inserted into view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `$interpolate` service and `$scope.$watch` take a look at this jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/6u45asg9/

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$interpolate) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!';
  //this template comes from json
  $scope.template = " {{hello}} {{world}} and have a good time";
  //this template comes from json   

  var updateTemplate = function(oldVal,newVal,scope){
     scope.fromjson = $interpolate(scope.template)(scope);
  }

  $scope.$watch('hello', updateTemplate );
  $scope.$watch('world', updateTemplate );

});
```

Of course you should move `$watch` to link function in your directive and pass `hello` and `world` as scope variable to this directive - this is just a quick example how you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you want is this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!'
  //this template comes from json
  $scope.fromjson = function(){
     return $scope.hello + " " + $scope.world + " and have a good time";
  };
});

app.directive('helloworld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<textarea>{{fromjson()}}</textarea>'
  };
});
```

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/8YrIjeyt9Xdj2Cf7Izr5?p=preview

The problem with your code is that when you declare `$scope.fromjson = "{{hello}} {{world}} and have a good time"` you are not binding anything, you are just assiging that string to the `fromjson` property.

**EDIT**:

As HeberLZ pointed out in the comment bellow, it would be much more efficient to do this instead:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!'
});

app.directive('helloworld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<textarea>{{ hello + " " + world + " and have a good time"}}</textarea>'
  };
});
```

Comment: The first one won't update after you change hello and/or world. This second one on the other hand will update but will also introduce a leak in performance because of how the AngularJS framework works· People should NEVER execute functions inside interpolations {{ }} as Angular doesnt know in each digest cicle if it has changed and will reexecute and reexecute the function many times

Comment: @HeberLZ I just made an update based on your comment, thanks!

Comment: I like this one more than my own answer, i didn't pull the string about them having scope inheritance because of not defining the scope attribute inside the directive. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

One way would be something like this:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!'
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('helloworld', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'hello': '=',
      'world': '='
    },
    link: function(scope){
      scope.jsonFromServer = '';
      $http.get('someUrl').then(function(response){
        scope.jsonFromServer = response.data;
      });

      var updateFromjson = function(){
        scope.fromjson = scope.hello + ' ' + scope.world + ' ' + scope.jsonFromServer;
      }

      scope.$watch('hello', updateFromjson);
      scope.$watch('world', updateFromjson);
    }
    template: '<textarea>{{fromjson}}</textarea>'
  };
});
```

Body:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="hello">
  <input ng-model="world">
  <helloworld hello="hello" world="world"></helloworld>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = 'Hello';
  $scope.world = 'World!'
  //this template comes from json
  $scope.aDiffFunc = function() {
      return $scope.hello + " " + $scope.world + " and have a good time";
  };
  //this template comes from json

});

app.directive('helloworld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<textarea>{{aDiffFunc()}}</textarea>'
  };
});
```

this should be it??

http://plnkr.co/edit/ygA4U0v7fnuIbqAilrP7?p=preview

Comment: Yep, That would work too, but it won't keep updating if you make changes to "$scope.hello" or "$scope.world", that's why I put it in a function ;)

Comment: don't put functions inside interpolations, they make the function execute an enormous amount of time on big applications because of the quantity of digest cycles